# Blender snap (linux, specifically Ubuntu 17.04) very slow / freezing when in material view

Tags: interface, performance, linux

I recently downloaded the Blender snap from Ubuntu Software because it seems to be always up to date, Then I opened one of my projects to continue working on, then it just freezed for a sec then started to move but very slowly (2-5fps) Then I changed the viewport mode to Solid and it returned normal. Did anyone encounter the same problem and found some way to solve it? I would like to solve it because I prefer to use the snap as it is very easy to update through Ubuntu Software, while manually updating Blender by downloading from blender.org is a little bit harder and takes more time.

**UPDATE**
Because I cannot add filmic blender to the snap, I decided to just download the latest version of Blender for blender.org and use that.
But this does not solve the problem.